# Multiple updates on a single field causes "Updating the path 'X' would create a conflict at 'X'" in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following update operation:

```
private async onCategoryImagesModified(data: ModifiedFilesEventData) {
        this.categoryModel
            .findByIdAndUpdate(data.resourceId, {
                $pullAll: { images: data.removedFiles || [] },
                $addToSet: { images: { $each: data.addedFiles || [] } }
            }).catch(error => this.logger.warn(error))
}
```

Basically, every time images of model `category` changes I want to update the document by removing all the removed paths from `images` **and** adding the new paths to `images`.

I get that I can't reference the same field more than once inside an update, but is there a way to do this **without** 2 separate update operations?

Comment: if you can give the data, and how you want them to be after the update, you can change a field many times in 1 update, using pipeline updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get that I can't reference the same field more than once inside an update

The update will not support the same field more than once, if you want to do this in the single query you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `images` and remove the input elements by `$not` and `$in`
- `$setUnion` to get unique elements from input elements and `images` field

```
private async onCategoryImagesModified(data: ModifiedFilesEventData) {
  let stages = [];
  // remove fields
  if (data.removedFiles) {
    stages.push({
      $set: {
        images: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$images",
            cond: { $not: { $in: ["$$this", data.removedFiles] } }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // add fields
  if (data.addedFiles) {
    stages.push({
      $set: { images: { $setUnion: ["$images", data.addedFiles] } }
    });
  }

  this.categoryModel
    .findByIdAndUpdate(data.resourceId, [stages])
    .catch(error => this.logger.warn(error))
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ak-W6qHmRyd)

Comment: This will treat ```images``` as a set right? only unique values will be there?

Comment: yes, this will treat `images` as a set and it will be unique.